# Selective wireless power transfer

Tags: power-supply, wireless, wireless-charging

It is possibile to power on a single led (in a led panel) using wireless powering?
I know the possibility to transfer power by wireless, but, is there a way to transfer power with high precision (1mm) ?

Comment: What do you mean by *high precision*?

Comment: Is it possible: Yes. Can it be done with current commercial off the shelf items: maybe. Can an inexperienced hobbyist do it: probably not.

Comment: Does pointing a laser at a solar cell count?